# PowerShell - Script to search file contents for keywords

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I have the below script which will search a folder location for any files containing the word '**5047373**'. However it is only able to check text files it seems. It needs to be able to search across multiple types of files including word, csv, xlsx , pdf, txt etc.

```
   Get-ChildItem “C:\Documents” -recurse | Select-String -pattern “5047373” | group path | select name
```

Answer (score 1):

since Select-String uses regex by default, you can build a regex OR list. something like this ...

```
$ThingsToLookFor = @(
    'One'
    '22'
    'Three'
    '4444'
    'Five'
    )

$TTLF_Regex = $ThingsToLookFor -join '|'

'A demo line of text with 4444 embedded in it.' -match $TTLF_Regex
```

output = `True`

hope that helps,
lee

Comment: I'd recommend `$TTLF_Regex = ($ThingsToLookFor | % { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join "|"` in case some of the words include regex operators.

Comment: Thank for that but I was looking for it to output the file location of any words matched.

Comment: @DonCruickshank - that is something i never would have thot of ... until it happened to me. thanks for the idea! [*grin*]

Comment: to `dcraven` - you may want to edit your original question to state that more clearly. i have re-read your post and still don't see that implied at all. [*grin*] if you need the in-file context for each match, then you will need to use some other method.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Windows Desktop Search. PowerShell doesn't come with the ability to search these file types by default but you can easily install a package on Windows 10 to use the search facility you get in Explorer:

```
Install-Package PsSearch -Scope CurrentUser
```

Once you've got that installed then you should be able to search from a list of words in a text file as follows. Put your words in a text file `words.txt`, e.g.:

```
5047373
123456
Apple
Pie
```

Then you could do:

```
$SearchResults = foreach ($Word in (Get-Content "words.txt")) {
    Search-Index $Word
}
```

Then `$SearchResults` is the list of files that matched the query list. From that, you can get a unique list of filenames with this:

```
$FileNames = ($SearchResults | Select-Object -Unique FullName).FullName
```

Comment: Thanks @Don this only seems to work with reading text files. It doesn't work when reading CSV files which is mostly where I need to check.

Comment: OK, it would be best to edit your question to include how you want to involve the CSV files.

Comment: Thanks Don I have updated my question. I have multiple files including csv, xlsx, pdf and similar to a File Explorer search I need a PowerShell equivalent if that makes sense that will search a folder location for any word matches from the list.